# How to run a PHP function concurrently against an array?

Tags: php

I have a PHP web app which scrapes a search engine for a given keyword.

Currently the app is looping through an array of keywords running the scrape function one keyword at a time.

This is OK at the moment because the number of keywords is fairly small, but it won't scale well.

I think the best way to go will be to select a smaller set of keywords from the mysql db using limit, and then run the scrape function concurrently against the entire array. Once that set has finished, I'll move on to the next set.

But I'm stuck with how to run the function concurrently against the array.

How would you handle this?

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer: php is not good at concurrent programming, it was not designed for it. Currently the only option is to use pcntl extension and fork other processes but  it's not very efficient. If you want to write multi-threaded programs my advice to you is to use Java instead.

Comment: If by "concurrently" you mean "on multiple threads," then no.  PHP has no multithreading facilities.

Comment: Why Ew? I like Java, because of concurrency and also when I need to write something for desktop with GUI

Comment: Thanks everyone. I thought the replies would be along those lines. I might move the scraping part to Ruby and use Nokogiri.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any concurrency in PHP itself, but if you get your search result with cURL there is a [multiple-request feature](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) in the cURL extension, so you could parallelize at least the fetching of the results.

Comment: You can request we pages to be downloaded at the same time, however you cannot parse them at the same time once downloaded. php is not multithreaded language, period. Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: That's what I said. As the fetching usally takes longer than the parsing, that feature may be worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");

function test_alter(&$item1, $key, $prefix)
{
    $item1 = "$prefix: $item1";
}

function test_print($item2, $key)
{
    echo "$key. $item2<br />\n";
}

echo "Before ...:\n";
array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');

array_walk($fruits, 'test_alter', 'fruit');
echo "... and after:\n";

array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');
?>
```

Comment: This is not concurrent, it's sequential. Concurrent means multiple operations at the same time, sequential (php way) is one step at a time.

Comment: Yes. Look at author's words: "Once that set has finished, I'll move on to the next set." Thus, I think he meant exactly sequential processing whole array (small portion of data from DB), not whole data.